# k8s obtained cluster IP is different from the set cluster IP

Tags: kubernetes

Today my colleague asked me a question, I don't know how to answer, he explained that "service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12" has been set, but why are there still different cluster ips in the k8s cluster.

Who can help me answer this question ?

thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`...he explained that "service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12" has been set`

The use of CIDR `10.96.0.0/12` will have range start from `10.96.0.1` to `10.111.255.254`. There is nothing wrong with those IP(s) in the screenshot.